# Is there a way to back up Amazon Market via Titanium Backup without 2Gb backup file size?

Tags: amazon-appstore, titanium-backup

I was trying to figure out what was taking to much space on my SD card, and found out the following file in Titanium Backup directory:

```
com.amazon.venezia-20120409-052438.tar.gz    - 2,020,523,913 bytes (2Gb)
```

This is obviously a backup of Amazon App Store.

I am guessing the size is so large because for some reason, the Amazon App Store app stores a copy of ALL the apps installed through Amazon App Store (including several very big games, thus 2G size).

**Questions:**

- Is this theory correct? (the file being 2Gb tgz file, I'm somewhat hesitant to gunzip and untar it to investigate the internals).
- If so, is the size due to storing a copy of installed .apk files in Amazon App Store itself, or the cache? (I suspect the former, since cache backup is turned off in my TitaniumBackup  preferences).
- How can I back up just the Amazon App Store app and not all the apps downloaded from Amazon with it (since, obviously, those are backed up separately by Titanium Backup anyway)

Comment: @RichardBorcsik - deleted all the useless comments, since your answer is self contained now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon app store downloads APK files to a folder that Titanium Backup considers external app data. You can regularly clean out this folder or choose one of the following:

1. Create a label, and add Amazon Appstore to it. Now go into settings and under Backup external app data choose.
   "Enable for apps outside of choosen label" now pick the label that you added Amazon too.
2. Inside TB's settings under Backup external app data choose "Enable if it's smaller than choosen size" and enter a value that you're comfortable with.

Comment: #1 worked perfectly once I realized that for some reason Titanium Backup does NOT recognize Folder Organizer labels for Preferences (though it does for filters)